# Rendering chart in the background

Tags: highcharts

I have a large dataset (multiple nested json) which I am using to create 4 line charts using highchart. As the volume of data grows I begin to see a higher rendering time, which is normal. I was wondering if there might be a way to render a part of the data (say, 15 days' data), and then render the rest of the data in the background and make the enable the tabs (1m, 3m, 6 m, ...) as the data is rendered.

Thanks,
Sukrit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possbile, you need to prepare script which will return you a part of data.

See the exampel of lazy loading http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/lazy-loading

Comment: Thanks Sebastien. I've looked at the example. It looks like they are using grouping of data. I need the data and the visualization to be accurate. I'll take a look at it a bit more. Just finding it a bit of a challenge to locate the right syntax for lazy loading. Highcharts has surprisingly little documentation on their website.